# What's the difference between the build and create methods in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

[The Factory Girl introduction](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) delineates the difference between `FactoryGirl.build()` and `FactoryGirl.create()`:

```
# Returns a User instance that's not saved
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

# Returns a saved User instance
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

I still don't understand the practical differences between the two. Can someone give an example where you would want to use one and not the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The `create()` method persists the instance of the model while the `build()` method keeps it only on memory.

Personally, I use the `create()` method only when persistence is really necessary since writing to DB makes testing time consuming.

e.g.

I create users to authentication with `create()` because my authentication engine queries the DB.

To check if a model has an attribute the `build()` method will do because no DB access is required.

```
it{Factory.build(:user).should respond_to(:name)}
```

### Update

"There is one exception that build actually 'creates' when you are building associations, i.e your association are no longer in memory but persisted. Keep that in mind" –  Shakes

Comment: There is one exception that build actually 'creates' when you are building associations, i.e your association are no longer in memory but persisted. Keep that in mind

Comment: @Shakes, I don't work in rails anymore. I'll check that as soon as I can.

Comment: Has anyone made a tool to replace each instance of `create` with `build`, and undo it if the test fails?

Comment: Does `#create` read and return the persisted object from disk, or does it return the object that's in memory after persisting it? In other words, is is doing `create(...)` equivalent to `create(...).reload`?

Answer (score 22):

Using `FactoryGirl.build(:factory_name)` does not persist to the db and does not call `save!`, so your Active Record validations will not run. This is much faster, but validations might be important.

Using `FactoryGirl.create(:factory_name)` will persist to the db and will call Active Record validations. This is obviously slower but can catch validation errors (if you care about them in your tests).

Comment: Or, you could just do FactoryGirl.build(:factory_name).valid? which run validations without saving to database.

Answer (score 5):

`FactoryGirl.create()` will create new object and associations (if the factory has any) for it. They will all be persisted in a database. Also, it will trigger both model and database validations. 
Callbacks `after(:build)` and `after(:create)` will be called after the factory is saved. Also `before(:create)` will be called before the factory is saved.

`FactoryGirl.build()` won't save an object, but will still make requests to a database if the factory has associations. It will trigger validations only for associated objects.
Callback `after(:build)` will be called after the factory is built.

Note that in most cases when testing models are best to use `build_stubbed` for better performance. Read more about it [here](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-build-vs-build_stub).