# Calling ActiveRecord .reload method in update action causing spec object to have nil id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller, factory-bot

**ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED**

After adding `.reload` in order to prevent the dog_vaccination_records from saving to the database twice with different data, a few of my specs fail with the same error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find DogVaccinationRecord without an ID
     # ./app/controllers/dog_vaccination_record_controller.rb:9:in `update'
```

Setting a breakpoint inside of the failing spec and calling `dog_medical_records` or `dog_vaccination_records` does indeed return both objects with `nil` ids, but correct information otherwise:

```
#<DogVaccinationRecord:0x007fed0bf322d0
id: nil,
dog_record_id: 6,
archived_at: nil,
created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil>
```

What is it about `.reload` that causes the id of an object in the test database to be `nil`? A `nil` ID would make sense if I called `.reload` in create, but why in update is that object not already in the database?

I've done a bit of Googling and wonder if the error has anything to do with the `.reload` only reloading "the latest code in the console environment" and not "re-initializing existing objects" a la [this explanation of `.reload`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427596/rails-console-reload-not-reflecting-changes-in-model-files-what-could-be-poss).

TL:DR: Help me understand how the `.reload` method works, which should give me a better idea of how `.reload` is affecting my specs.

Initialization of dog_medical_record in the spec via FactoryGirl:

```
dog_vaccination_record = FactoryGirl.build(:dog_vaccination_record_base, dog_medical_record: dog.dog_medical_record)
```

DogMedicalRecords controller update action:

```
def update
  @dog_vaccination_records = @dog.dog_record.dog_vaccination_records.decorate
  if @dog_medical_records.update_attributes(params[:dog_medical_records])
    @dog_vaccination_records.reload.update_attributes(params[:dog_vaccination_records]) if params[:dog_vaccination_records]

    @dog_medical_records.errors.add(:dog_vaccination_records, "fields are not valid") unless @dog_vaccination_records.valid?
    initialize_resource
  end

respond_with @dog_medical_records
end
```

**EDIT 07/26/2018**

The issue was that I was using `.build` to build a FactoryBot object, when I should have used `.create`. `.build` is like calling `.new` without a `.save`, while using `.create` creates the object and saves it to the database.

Comment: Your `@dog_vaccination_records` is not saved in the database to begin with (from what you've shown us). So it can't be reloaded.

Comment: Also, aren't you confusing `reload!` from rails console and `reload` from ActiveRecord?

Comment: Sorry @SergioTulentsev, I've had to refactor this code a bit to protect the project. I've fixed all mentions of `.reload!` to just `.reload` as it is in the controller's update action.

Yes, I was confusing it with the ActiveRecord method.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I was about to ask you what you meant by `@dog_vaccination_records` not being saved to begin with. But then I changed that `FactoryGirl.build()` to `FactoryGirl.create` and the ID appears. That's what you were talking about, wasn't it? The difference between `.build` and `.create`?

Comment: Exactly that, yes.

Comment: That's the crucial part of your question - that you've used FactoryBot's `build` instead of `create`. Care to update the question for others to find?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @SergioTulentsev and question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

The issue was that I was using .build to build a FactoryBot object, when I should have used .create. .build is like calling .new without a .save, while using .create creates the object and saves it to the database [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098031/whats-the-difference-between-the-build-and-create-methods-in-factorygirl).