# How do I unit test the current_user RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, simplecov

I have this method to check if the user is admin:

```
def admin?
  current_user.admin == true
end
```

The unit test is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe StubController do
  describe '.admin?' do
    it "should tell if the user is admin" do
      user = User.create!(email: "i@i.com", password:'123456', role: "admin", name: "Italo Fasanelli")

      result = user.admin?

      expect(result).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is, simplecov is telling me that this part `current_user.admin == true` is not covered.

How do I test the current_user in this test?

Comment: Have you used auth hems like Device?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the gem Devise

Comment: Where you declared`admin?` method, model or controller?

Comment: In the ApplicationController. But I made this StubController that only inherit methods from ApplicationController and I can test its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, move the `admin?` method to `User` model so that it can be reused across Model-View-Controller.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end
end
```

You can use this method wherever you have access to the instance of `User`. So `current_user.admin?` would also work across views and controller.

Now you should write test for model not the controller. Also I noticed that you create user model object manually instead of using Factory. Use [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) to create required instances for testing.

Here is a quick spec assuming there is factory is set for user

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe '.admin?' do
    context 'user has role set as admin' do
      let!(:user) { build(:user, role: 'admin') }

      it 'returns true' do
        expect(user).to be_admin
      end
    end

    context 'user has role set as non admin' do
      let!(:user) { build(:user, role: 'teacher') }

      it 'returns true' do
        expect(user).not_to be_admin
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and explanation sir. I'm already using FactoryBot, but I totally forgot to update the test with it. If I may, I'd like to ask you more about this line let!(:user) { build (:user, role: 'admin') }  this syntax belongs to FactoryBot? I'm starting at web dev and I only know FactoryBot with this syntax: create(:user, role: 'admin')

Comment: Learn here `build` vs `create` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098031/whats-the-difference-between-the-build-and-create-methods-in-factorygirl

Comment: Got it now. Can't thank you enough for that. Have a great day!